# Accessing shell script on remote server

Tags: php, linux, bash, raspberry-pi, shell-exec

So first of all I have 2 Servers:

1. Raspberry pi
2. Linux Debian server

The pi has a script that displays the current Temperature in a room.

This is the script :

```
#!/bin/bash
i2cset -y 1 0x48 0xEE
dte=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
tme=$(date +%H:%M:%S)
hexraw=$(i2cget -y 1 0x48 0xAA w)
msb=$(echo ${hexraw:4:2})
lsb=$(echo ${hexraw:2:1})
dec=$(printf "%d\n" "0x$msb$lsb")
temp=$(echo "scale=1; $dec/16" | bc)

echo $temp
exit
```

Displaying the temperature on the pi's website works fine.
But then I have another script on the linux server that takes the value of the pi's script:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(ssh pi@172.16.248.210 sudo /home/pi/CurrTemp;)
echo $x
```

This works too. But when I want to display the Temp on my Linux server website(with shell_exec()) it doesn't work. The var_dump is empty.

PHP:

I've tried to write it with a "sudo".

I've changed the script owner to root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh` authentication does not work since the web server can't (and should) access your ssh keys.

You have to options (where the latter is definitely preferred!):

- Create another ssh key for the web server on the Debian server and add to `allowed_keys` on the PI. You may restrict the key to allow only that command.
- Create a little web service on the PI and output the temperature in plain text, xml, json or whatever. The use `file_get_contents()` to obtain the file over HTTP, like this using a plain text file:

*temperature.php* on raspberry pi:

```
<?php

echo shell_exec('/home/pi/CurrTemp');
```

*temperature.php* on Debian:

```
<?php

$temperature = file_get_contents('http://172.16.248.210/temperature.php');

echo $temperature;
```

Comment: Excuse me I forgot to mention that I already created a RSA key on the both sides. Do you mean writing the output of my "pi's" script in an json file ?

Comment: No, you should output the value over HTTP. Just `echo`. Use plain text for first tests.

Comment: So you mean i should ignore the one script on my linux server and put the output of the currTemp in HTTP ? and if yes how does it work ?

Comment: On the pi's site im using .htaccess could that block the communication ?

Comment: why don't you test this? I can't answer this, since I can't access your pi.

Comment: Hey, you need to figure it out for yourself. That's the fun!